# Very High Errors in Deep Belief Network with Nolearn in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, theano, lasagne, nolearn

I'm new to Nolearn and Theano in general. When I tried the code in [a Nolearn tutorial](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/09/22/getting-started-deep-learning-python/), I get extremely high error rates of 0.9!

Why am I getting such high errors while the tutorial is getting errors of 0.005? Is anyone else able to reproduce this problem?

Using Theano 0.7.0, Lasagne v0.1, nolearn v0.5 on OS X Yosemite.

**Output**

```
[DBN] fitting X.shape=(46900, 784)
[DBN] layers [784, 300, 10]
[DBN] Fine-tune...
100%

Epoch 1:
100%

  loss 2.30829815265
  err  0.901340505464
  (0:00:30)
Epoch 2:
100%

  loss 2.30304712187
  err  0.902813353825
  (0:00:34)
Epoch 3:
100%

  loss 2.30303548692
  err  0.90072148224
  (0:00:34)
Epoch 4:
100%

  loss 2.30297605197
  err  0.902322404372
  (0:00:28)
Epoch 5:
100%

  loss 2.30295462556
  err  0.901191086066
  (0:00:26)
Epoch 6:
100%

  loss 2.30293222366
  err  0.898352117486
  (0:00:33)
Epoch 7:
100%

  loss 2.30283567033
  err  0.901425887978
  (0:00:34)
Epoch 8:
100%

  loss 2.30283342522
  err  0.90059340847
  (0:00:35)
Epoch 9:
100%

  loss 2.30283433199
  err  0.902813353825
  (0:00:33)
Epoch 10:
  loss 2.30279696997
  err  0.897861168033
  (0:00:33)
```

**Code**

```
# import the necessary packages
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn import datasets
from nolearn.dbn import DBN
import numpy as np

# grab the MNIST dataset (if this is the first time you are running
# this script, this make take a minute -- the 55mb MNIST digit dataset
# will be downloaded)
print "[X] downloading data..."
dataset = datasets.fetch_mldata("MNIST Original")

# scale the data to the range [0, 1] and then construct the training
# and testing splits
(trainX, testX, trainY, testY) = train_test_split(
    dataset.data / 255.0, dataset.target.astype("int0"), test_size = 0.33)

# train the Deep Belief Network with 784 input units (the flattened,
# 28x28 grayscale image), 300 hidden units, 10 output units (one for
# each possible output classification, which are the digits 1-10)
dbn = DBN(
    [trainX.shape[1], 300, 10],
    learn_rates = 0.3,
    learn_rate_decays = 0.9,
    epochs = 10,
    verbose = 1)
dbn.fit(trainX, trainY)
```

**Classification report**

[image]

Comment: I had the same problem with several different libraries. I resorted to matlab at last.

Comment: @sudomakeinstall2 Any idea what the problem was?

Comment: Sorry, but no I couldn't find the problem.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. I copied and pasted the code provided in the question and ran it without modifications (after installing nolearn via pip). I get good error rate outputs (err = 0.00508025956284 after 10 epochs). Are you sure you've got the latest version of Theano, Lasagne, and nolearn? Maybe try updating to the GitHub versions instead of the pip release versions?

Comment: Switched to Keras and life became better :)